# Debian libsll conflict

Tags: debian, conflict, libssl

I would like to install Viber under Debian 10.2

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of viber:
 viber depends on libssl1.0.0; however:
  Package libssl1.0.0 is not installed.
```

The actual version installed is 1.1.1

```
# apt-cache policy libssl1.1
libssl1.1:
  Installed: 1.1.1d-0+deb10u2
  Candidate: 1.1.1d-0+deb10u2
  Version table:
 *** 1.1.1d-0+deb10u2 500
```

I tried to fix it by the following command

```
# apt-get install libssl1.0.0=1.1.1d-0+deb10u2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '1.1.1d-0+deb10u2' for 'libssl1.0.0' was not found
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the libssl1.0.0 package from http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/o/openssl/libssl1.0.0_1.0.1t-1+deb8u12_amd64.deb.
If you are using Debian 10 64-bit, you will also have to install the multiarch-support package - you can get it from the Debian repo.
Let me know if the following sequence of commands works for you:

```
sudo apt -y install multiarch-support wget
wget http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/o/openssl/libssl1.0.0_1.0.1t-1+deb8u12_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libssl1.0.0_1.0.1t-1+deb8u12_amd64.deb
wget https://download.cdn.viber.com/cdn/desktop/Linux/viber.deb
sudo dpkg -i viber.deb
```